# Accessibility between objects (instances) of the same class

Tags: java

> When one object of a class has a reference to another object of
>   the same class, the first object can access all the second object’s
>   data and methods (including those that are private).

I took this sentence from a book. But I couldn't figure out actually what it means.

Answer (score 2):

It means that private members are visible to other instances of the same class. For example:

```
class A {
  private int v;

  public boolean isSameV(A other) {
    return this.v == other.v; // can acccess other.v
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good question actually, I faced similar problem when I started learning Java, here is how it looks in practice:

```
public class A {

    private String example;
    protected int anotherOne;

    public A(){

    }

    public A(A a){
        this.example = a.example; // here we get access to private member of another object of same class
        this.anotherOne = a.anotherOne; // it works for protected as well
    }

    // This works for methods not just constructor, lets consider we want to swap value of example:
    public void swapExample(A a){
        String temp = a.example;
        a.example = this.example;
        this.example = temp;
    } 

}
```

Comment: @azro I'm quite sure that this is what he OP is asking about, current instance of object is getting reference of another object of same class, standard example of this is copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`Private` fields can be accessed from inside of the class, by this construction you can access all the field of an instance of `Foo` without getters and setters when you are in class `Foo` :

```
public class Foo {

    private String name;

    public int sumLetter(Foo b) {
        return this.name.length() + b.name.length();
    }
}
```

---

The doc : [`Declaring Member Variables`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) :

- *private modifier* — the field is accessible only within its own class.

Answer (score 1):

It means that if you have a class that looks like this

```
public class A {
    private int number;
    private A otherInstance;

    public int number2;

    public void DoStuff() {
        ...
    }    
}
```

you can access `A.number` in the `DoStuff` method (or any other class method) even although `number` is actually `private`.

e.g.

```
public class A {
    ...
    public void DoStuff() {
        this.otherInstance.number = 42;
                          ^^^^^^^
                  cannot access private members here
    }
}
```

is perfectly fine, while

```
public class B {
    private A aInstance;

    public void DoStuffToo() {
        this.aInstance.number = 42;
    }
}
```

would not compile, because `B` cannot access `A`'s private members.